# invalid byte 2 of 2-byte UTF-8 sequence in resource files after importing the worklight template

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I'm trying to create a Worklight project in Worklight Studio 6.1 from a template. It's a straight forward process as described here: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.dev.doc%2Fstudio_ext_assets%2Fc_wl_project_templates.html

However I'm getting "invalid byte 2 of 2-byte UTF-8 sequence" exceptions on some of the settings.xml files inside the android environment's native resources when trying to compile newly created project.
The files are in utf-8 inside the template and I have utf-8 set up for my workspace  file encoding ( Preferences->General->Workspace ).

But after extracting stuff from the template ( which is really a zip bundle ) looks like it changes encoding somehow.

Problem goes away when you try to re-save .xml file (for example - open it, add a char somewhere, delete it and save). But this is not an option since we are going to deliver the template to a customer and this will affect the 'user experience'.

Also, the same exact template works fine on linux platform. I saw this issue on windows.

Has anybody experienced this before and could share any info on how to fix it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that under Preferences->General->Workspace in Eclipse, the default text file encoding is set to UTF-8 and not US-ASCII (usually by default it is set to ASCII). This should take care of the encoding problems.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Thing is I have already set that up as I mentioned in my question. I've also set utf-8 for required content types ( Preferences -> Content Types ) just in case. Still see the issue.

Comment: Oh ok, it was worth a try. :P